# OpenGL - Keeping rendering stationary when pivot-point changes

Tags: c, opengl

I am working a on a problem such that:

- a cube is rendered in 3D space, using X/Y/Z co-ordinate system, such that the centre of the cube is at origin (0, 0, 0).
- now, the cube is rotated R degrees, say 30, around each (X, Y, and Z) axes, with the origin as being the pivot point.
- now, the pivot point is changed to, let's say (1, 0, 0). The object's orientation will now change since the previous rotation was around origin, and now the rotation (same angle, 30 degrees) is around (1, 0, 0).
- however, after the pivot-point change, I want to auto-adjust the position along X, Y, Z axes, such that the object ***appears*** to be retaining the same orientation.

Any pointers on how I can achieve that?

Comment: You have your coordinate spaces all confused.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - I have edited the question. Please let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: I think you'd need to write a short, self-contained example that demonstrates what you've done so far, and how it doesn't work.